# MongoDB Aggregation in custom Spring Data @Query

Tags: annotations, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Anyone know how to shoehorn MongoDB aggregate queries into spring-data custom @Query?

I would like to group my entities and retrieve all the latest version by date.

The aggregate query is

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    { $sort: { url: 1, checkedOn: 1 } },
    { 
      $group: { 
        _id: {url: "$url", path: "$path" },
        lastChecked: { $last: "$checkedOn" }
      }
    }
  ])
```

This runs fine and returns a collection like this:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "url" : "http://www.google.co.uk",
                "path" : "/about"
            },
            "lastChecked" : ISODate("2015-03-17T11:43:01.222Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "url" : "http://www.google.co.uk",
                "path" : "/about2"
            },
            "lastChecked" : ISODate("2015-03-17T11:43:04.213Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I'd like to do this as part of a spring-data custom query:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "healthcheck", path = "healthcheck")
public interface LinkRepository extends MongoRepository<Link, String> {

    @Query("{ 'status' : { $gt: 299 }, 'path' : ?0 }" )
    List<CheckedLink> findByPathAndInvalid(@Param("path") String path);

    @Query(**aggregate query goes here**)
    List<CheckedLink> findByLatest();

}
```

I can't put the aggregate query directly into @Query because the resulting collection is not directly mapped to the Link object.

Only reference I can find is on an old Spring-Sandbox project but this has not been updated since 2013:
https://github.com/hantsy/spring-sandbox/wiki/spring-data-mongo#custom-query

Comment: In case anyone finds this question...

I ended up moving from MongoDB to PostgreSQL just so I can do the aggregation.  Pity, I'm sure that MongoDB would have been a nicer solution.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Query` annotation can be only used to fill the query part of a mongo request. As other annotation classes are `CountQuery`, `DeleteQuery` and `ExistsQuery`, I assume that this is not possible using an annotation.